# Laravel get 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I had laravel project on share hosting, and my structure app is

```
/home/username

`->fontEndApps ( my laravel apps )`

`->backendApps ( my laravel apps )`

`->public_html`
```

in public html I put the index.php, htaccess and admin folder, in admin folder there is index.php and htaccess

backend is working fine but the front end when I try to access www.domain.com/segment1 or www.domain.com/segment1/segment2 I always got 500 internal server error, and this is my htaccess file for front end and back end

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

please help me to figure out this problem

Comment: Comment out `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` line and retest

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is with **.htaccess** file. In goDaddy they wont set `RewriteBase` so you have to give it in your **.htaccess** file. The complete code would like this. This worked with my laravel portfolio [site](http://www.pattanath.com)

```
 <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
#For REST support
       Allow from all
 </Limit>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / # <------------ This one you missed

    #Just to redirect to www.site.com when only site.com comes
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
    #end of codes

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hey, where did you put this? In public folder, or root?

Comment: @Ned In `public` folder. Apache looks into public folder.

Comment: Works very with Laravel 5.5 on 1and1 hosting with php7.1

Comment: It is not working on Hostgator.

Answer (score 6):

After a couple of hours searching, this solved the problem:

Make sure **index.php** within /public_html has **644** permissions (mine was 664 and that was the cause of the Internal Server Error).

Answer (score 4):

I must comment this lines in .htaccess and it works:

```
#<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
#    Options -MultiViews
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the **Vendor** folder uploaded in the server it can **cause 500 error**.